# How to tell (GNU) make that a rule consumes several cores?

Tags: gnu-make

I use -j to speed up compilation and testing but some tests use more than one process, can I tell this to make in the tests' rules so that e.g. -j4 doesn't start 4 jobs in parallel that each use 4 cores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> some tests use more than one process, can I tell this to make in the tests' rules

Nope, you cannot.

You can build in parallel and then run your test in non-parallel mode. Or run some tests on parallel and others in non-parallel mode.